# Surjectivity of a map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a curve and $D\in\mathrm{Div}(C)$. Suppose $W$ is the canonical divisor. Let $g\in L(D)$ be such that $g\not\in L(D-P)$ for all $P\in C$ and $P\leq W-D$. Then one can show (given in *Algebraic Curves* by Fulton) that the following map is injective: $$\phi\colon L(W-D)/L(0)\longrightarrow L(W)/L(D)$$ given by $\phi ([f]):=[fg]$, where $[\cdot]$ denotes the residue class. I want to know when the map $\phi$ is *surjective* i.e. an isomorphism.

Clearly $\phi$ is an isomorphism when $D=0$ or $D=W$. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: What do you mean by $P\leq W-D$?

Comment: @Brenin: $P$ can be thought of as a divisor: $1$ at the $P$th position and zero elsewhere.